# re.split: Find cause of split

Tags: python, regex

In the following example a string is splitted at the keywords `dolor sit`, `elitr sed` and `something else`.

What are my options to find out which keyword caused the split at a given position (see the expected output)?

```py
import re

example_input = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consetetur sadipscing elitr sed diam nonumy'
splitted_string = re.split('dolor sit|elitr sed|something else', example_input)

for (index, part) in enumerate(splitted_string, 1):
    if index == len(splitted_string):
        print (part.strip())
    else:
        print (part.strip(), '-', '???')
```

Output:

```
Lorem ipsum - ???
amet consetetur sadipscing - ???
diam nonumy
```

Expected output:

```
Lorem ipsum - dolor sit
amet consetetur sadipscing - elitr sed
diam nonumy
```

Comment: you must use the re module?

Comment: No, the `re` module is not a requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture the split delimiters in a capture group by putting the regex in parenthesis like:

```
re.split(r'(dolor sit|elitr sed|something else)', example_input)
```

This will return a list of the split terms followed by the delimiter like:

```
['Lorem ipsum ', 'dolor sit', ' amet consetetur sadipscing ', 'elitr sed', ' diam nonumy']
```

With that you can iterate through this and pull out the delimiters.

```
import re
from itertools import zip_longest

example_input = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consetetur sadipscing elitr sed diam nonumy'
splits = re.split(r'(dolor sit|elitr sed|something else)', example_input)

for (part, delimiter)in zip_longest(splits[::2], splits[1::2]):
    print(part.strip(), '-', delimiter)
```

This will print:

> Lorem ipsum - dolor sit
>   amet consetetur sadipscing - elitr sed
>   diam nonumy - None

Answer (score 2):

This'd actually be a good place to use regular expressions, which with one operation you would consume the string and do a simple replace:

```
import re

string = '''
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consetetur sadipscing elitr sed diam nonumy
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consetetur sadipscing elitr sed diam nonumy

'''

print(re.sub(r'(dolor sit|elitr sed|something else)\s+', r'- \1\n', string))
```

which would output:

```
Lorem ipsum - dolor sit
amet consetetur sadipscing - elitr sed
diam nonumy
Lorem ipsum - dolor sit
amet consetetur sadipscing - elitr sed
diam nonumy
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

example_input = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consetetur sadipscing elitr sed diam nonumy'
splitted_string = re.split('dolor sit|elitr sed|something else', example_input)

for (index, part) in enumerate(splitted_string):
    next_index = index + 1 if index + 1 < len(splitted_string) else index

    next_part = example_input[example_input.find(part) +
                              len(part): example_input.find(splitted_string[next_index])]

    output = ' - ' + next_part if next_part else ''
    print(part.strip(), output)
```